# Python threading module. Return function output from Thread class instance?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, parallel-processing, return

I tried the following but it is for `multiprocess` not `threading`
[Python threading return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688011/python-threading-return-values)
[how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python) is a similar question but the answer also uses `multiprocess` and I would like to stay in the `threading` module.

When I create a `Thread` object, I'm not sure how to get the output of the function that it is targeting.  If I do `print` instead of `return` in my `choose` function, then it will print it out to the console but I can't actually use that in a more complicated program.

```
import threading
import numpy as np

def choose(seq,n=3):
    return(''.join(np.random.choice(list(seq),size=n)))

n_threads = 2
thread_list = []

alpha = "ABCD"
n = 2
print("STARTING...\n")

for i in range(n_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=choose,args=(alpha,n))
    t.start()
    #HOW CAN I GET VALUES FROM T? 
    thread_list.append(t)
    print("\nThread Count: " + str(threading.activeCount()))
print("\nEXITING...\n")
```

Comment: Please be aware that the `threading` and `multiprocessing` modules have _very_ similar functions and classes. I guess that that is why your answer was marked as being a duplicate. But the suggested dup. is likely [not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886090/return-value-from-thread)

Comment: @cfi thanks, the last answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886090/return-value-from-thread was what I was looking for.